# Do a curve fit for every serial number?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a curve fit for every serial number. My first idea was to do it with a group by or with a list and check my df for numbers in my list. But whatever method I can think of, I have to manually enter the serial numbers. Is there any way to check my column serial number and do the curve fit for the first serial number it finds then the second and so on?

Here is a part of my df:

```
    Date    Hour    Minute  Second  Seriel number   mrwSmpVWi   mrwSmpP
0   04.06.2019  0   0   1   701086  4.2 51
1   04.06.2019  0   0   1   701092  4.6 75
2   04.06.2019  0   0   1   701088  4.3 58
3   04.06.2019  0   0   2   701085  4.2 52
4   04.06.2019  0   0   2   701091  4.5 71
5   04.06.2019  0   0   2   701089  4.3 59
6   04.06.2019  0   0   3   701087  4.0 56
7   04.06.2019  0   0   4   701090  3.8 44
8   04.06.2019  0   10  0   701092  4.3 58
9   04.06.2019  0   10  0   701086  4.3 59
10  04.06.2019  0   10  1   701088  4.4 63
11  04.06.2019  0   10  1   701085  4.4 65
12  04.06.2019  0   10  1   701091  4.5 71
13  04.06.2019  0   10  2   701089  4.5 69
14  04.06.2019  0   10  3   701087  4.4 71
15  04.06.2019  0   10  4   701090  3.5 34
16  04.06.2019  0   20  0   701092  4.3 64
17  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701086  4.4 69
18  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701088  4.3 63
19  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701091  4.5 73
20  04.06.2019  0   20  1   701085  4.2 61
21  04.06.2019  0   20  2   701089  4.4 71
```

And this is how I want to do my curve fit:

```
x=ohlala.T.iloc[5]
y=ohlala.T.iloc[6]

def logifunc(x,c,a,b):
    return c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x)))

result, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x, y, p0=[110,400,-2])
```

My goal is to get a df like the picture.[image]

Comment: @1lk4I don't get what exactly you try to accomplish? You try to make `curve_fit` with usage of all parameters in column `Serial`?

Comment: I try to do a curve fit with every `mrwSmpVWi` and `mrwSmpP` for the serial number `701086` then get my results and to it for the seriel number `701092` and so on...

Comment: they need to by grouped by `Seriel number`? If no then you can simply add function results to new columns like `results`

Comment: Yes if I can do it without enter the seriel numbers manually that would be great.

Comment: see new updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is grouped by `Serial`then shipped to `data_fit` function. Returned fit values are loaded into 3 separate columns.

Input:

```
   Serial  mrwSmpVWi  mrwSmpP
0  701086        4.2       52
1  701087        4.3       61
2  701086        4.5       34
3  701087        3.2       22
4  701086        2.5       23
5  701087        4.2       34
```

Code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Serial': [701086, 701087, 701086, 701087, 701086, 701087], 'mrwSmpVWi': [4.2, 4.3, 4.5, 3.2, 2.5, 4.2], 'mrwSmpP': [52, 61, 34, 22,23, 34]})


def logifunc(x,c,a,b):
    return c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x)))


def data_fit(row, x, y):
    result, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x.values, y.values)
    row['a'] = result[0]
    row['b'] = result[1]
    row['c'] = result[2]
    return row

grouped_data = df.groupby('Serial')

for group_name, grouped_df in grouped_data:
    x = grouped_df['mrwSmpVWi']
    y = grouped_df['mrwSmpP']
    if x.shape[0] >= 3:
        df = df.apply(data_fit, args=(x,y), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
     Serial  mrwSmpVWi  mrwSmpP     a           b          c
0  701086.0        4.2     52.0  39.0  548.084806  16.941529
1  701087.0        4.3     61.0  39.0  548.084806  16.941529
2  701086.0        4.5     34.0  39.0  548.084806  16.941529
3  701087.0        3.2     22.0  39.0  548.084806  16.941529
4  701086.0        2.5     23.0  39.0  548.084806  16.941529
5  701087.0        4.2     34.0  39.0  548.084806  16.941529
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But in this case you need to enter the seriel numbers. I don#t know which or how many seriel numbers I will have in one df. Can I do it without enter `({'Serial': [701086, 701087], 'mrwSmpVWi': [4.2, 4.3], 'mrwSmpP': [52, 61]})` manually?

Comment: @1lk4 then where the data is coming from? You need to be more precise of describing the problem.

Comment: I want to get a df with the unknown values from my curve fit for every serial number. I added a picture to my question. the df is a csv with around 250,000 rows

Comment: @1lk4 still i don't know what you try to archive. The variables `a,b,c` need to by generated randomly?

Comment: No thats the point of a curve fit. I hava a x-axis and a y-axis and the curve fit gives me a function to connect the points with the best fit. Sorry if I didn't explain it very well. c,a and b are unknown and calculated in the curve fit.

Comment: the curve fit itself works fine. I just don't know how I can do it seperatly for every serial number

Comment: @1lk4 where are the data sets of `x, y` located?

Comment: `x=ohlala.T.iloc[5]
y=ohlala.T.iloc[6]` At this point I say my curve fit takte the column 5 from df:ohlala for x and column 6 from df:ohlala for y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221687/discussion-between-zaraki-kenpachi-and-1lk4).